# Hibernate MappingException: Logical column name cannot be null

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, wildfly-10

Any idea about the below hibernate mapping exception. The below is the complete stack strace and there is no information on from which table this exception has occured.

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Logical column name cannot be null
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:179)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:121)
        at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:667)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:193)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Logical column name cannot be null
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getPhysicalColumnName(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:972)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getPhysicalColumnName(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:966)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.TableBinder.bindFk(TableBinder.java:681)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1786)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1730)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1617)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:161)
        ... 7 more
```

Any idea about the root-cause of this exception is welcomed.

Comment: could you add your domain class and it mappings here, this error maybe for `ManyToMany` relations.

Comment: @RasoolGhafari thanks for the prompt reply. My ear contains multiple entity classes with ManyToMany relations, i couldn't find from which entity this error was thrown (stack strace also doesnt provide entity name) . Do you have any suggestion to identify the entity class

Answer (score 14):

I was seeing the same error, but I've managed to fix it. I stumbled upon this in the [documentation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Composite_Primary_Keys): "Many JPA implementations may throw seemingly inconsistent exceptions when not specifying referencedColumnName for every @JoinColumn annotation, which JPA requires (even if all referenced column names are equal to the ones in the referencing table)." Adding referencedColumnNames for every JoinColumn seemed to fix it for me.

And to help narrow down which class was giving me trouble, I set a breakpoint in org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.TableBinder::bindFk(), on line 682 where they call `referencedColumn = buildingContext.getMetadataCollector().getPhysicalColumnName(table, referencedColumn);` looking for when `referencedColumn` was empty or null.

Comment: Thanks @SnoopDougg 

As per your instruction, I kept the debug point and checked when referencedColumnName is coming as null, and added referenceColumName for that.

Answer (score 2):

Same answer as SnoopDougg.

With an additional information:
I had a `@ManyToMany` with `@JoinTable` containing

- `joinColumns` = {2 `@Joincolumns`}
- `inverseJoinColumns` = {2 `@Joincolumns`}

If I express all 4 @JoinColumn without any `referencedColumnName` ==> OK.

If I set one `referencedColumnName` ==> *Logical column name cannot be null*.

Solution: put the `referencedColumnName` on all @JoinColumn

Answer (score 0):

The root-cause of this exception can be different. I my case:

```
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas(value = {
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "null"))
})
```